# building Debian and Redhat packages with leiningen

Tags: clojure, rpm, leiningen, deb

Moving my project from Ant to Leiningen went so smoothly that I am looking at new things to include in the build process. one of which would be to **automatically create a .deb and .rpm file in the build**. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really great to have a lein plugin to help with this.  Since it already uses maven under the hood, you could look into using the maven-unix-plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/unix/) which can build .deb and .rpm files.  Otherwise if that looks annoying I don't think either package format is especially complex.  You could probably do it by hand in Clojure, in which case maybe looking at some example Ruby Rake tasks would help. (http://rubyforge.org/projects/pallet/)

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to write your own Leiningen plugin for this (which I hear is pretty easy), or use the [lein-scripts](http://clojars.org/lein-scripts) plugin and write a script/task for it.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same problem. I followed rosejn's suggestion and created a Leiningen plugin that uses the [RPM Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) to create an RPM. I've put it [here](https://github.com/ahjones/lein-rpm).